# Use parameters from regex with Nginx auth-url

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, oauth2-proxy

I use Ingress Nginx in my kubernetes cluster. I use Keycloak to manage users and groups, and oauth2-proxy. I filter access to some resources like :

User must belong to **group1** to access my.app.com/resources/**group1**/page.html

I'm able to enforce group checking with this ingress, works as expected :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://###/oauth2/auth?allowed_groups=group1"    
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://###/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
  name: app
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host:###
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /resources/group1/(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app
            port:
              number: 80
```

I would have to duplicate this ingress for every group, and for every new group added later... I'm looking for a way to input the group as a parameter from the path to auth-url. I tried :

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://###/oauth2/auth?allowed_groups=$3"    
...
         path: /resources(/|$)((\w*)(/|$)(.*))
```

But when I inspect the requests sent to oauth2, allowed_groups is empty. Tried with $2,$3,$4... it seems I just can't use the regex in this annotation.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In **Keycloak Auth Provider** by using the OAuth2 Proxy option `--allowed-group` flag, it is possible to specify which groups to limit the access for the authorization on group memberships.

Please create the required **client scope groups** by following the below steps to authorize Keycloak group membership with OAuth2 Proxy.

- Create a new Client Scope with the name **groups** in Keycloak.
- Include a mapper of type **Group Membership**.
- Set the **Token Claim Name** to groups or customize by matching it to
  the `--oidc-groups-claim` option of OAuth2 Proxy.
- If the **Full group path** option is selected, please include a "**/**"
  separator in the group names defined in the `--allowed-group` option of
  OAuth2 Proxy.

Example: `"/groupname" or "/groupname/group1".`

After creating the Client Scope named groups ,please attach it to the client as follows:

**Clients -> <your client's id> -> Client scopes -> Add client scope -> Select groups** and choose Optional.

This maps group memberships into the JWT tokens so that Oauth2 Proxy may evaluate them.The OAuth2 Proxy option `--allowed-group=/groupname` will now allow to filter on group membership.

The above information is derived from the [documentation](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/next/configuration/oauth_provider#keycloak-auth-provider).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, although the Keycloak configuration is already working for me. I have the setting : `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://###/oauth2/auth?allowed_groups=group1"` working great for group1, but I want to avoid hard-coding the group name in the ingress rules. Right now, I have to duplicate this ingress for every group, I'm looking for a way to input allowed_groups depending on the requested url.

Comment: is your issue resolved? let me know if you need any additional help.

Comment: So far I haven't found any solution to use regex patterns in the auth-url parameter. My only work around is to duplicate my ingress resource and hard-code groups in the yaml files.

Comment: Instead of a value, can you please try as mentioned in this document https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/features/endpoints/#auth 

allowed_groups: comma separated list of allowed groups

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing currently and it works as expected. My issue is that I have a different ingress resource for each group, I'm trying to have only one ingress resource by passing the group as a parameter. I beleive the issue is more about nginx-ingress regex than keycloak actually.